# How to split numerical values at the end of a string and then convert 1.4 x 10*4 to 1.4E4?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have been given an excel file which I will pull into R with `openxlsx` but I need to deal with splitting the character element of each cell from then numerical (that's probably ok using regex). But then there's the numerical part which is actually part numerical/part character. **E.g. 1.4 x 10*4** needs to be 1.4E4 or 1400. Any strategies anyone can think of for cleaning this up please? Note, there are merged cells which I've left in the example data.frame but which openxlsx will take care of. Any thought are much appreciated.

```
df<-data.frame(`Brilliance UTI Agar cfu/m3`=c(
0,
"Enterococcus spp 1.4 x 10*4",,

"Enterococcus spp 8.3 x 10*3",
0, ,

"Proteus 8 x 10*4",
"Enterococcus spp 1.7 x 10*3"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `gsub` here for a base R option:

```r
df$data <- gsub("\\b(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s*x\\s*10\\*(\\d+)\\b", "\\1E\\2", input)
df

                    data
1                      0
2 Enterococcus spp 1.4E4
3 Enterococcus spp 8.3E3
4                      0
5            Proteus 8E4
6 Enterococcus spp 1.7E3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(data=c("0",
                        "Enterococcus spp 1.4 x 10*4",
                        "Enterococcus spp 8.3 x 10*3",
                        "0",
                        "Proteus 8 x 10*4",
                        "Enterococcus spp 1.7 x 10*3"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. It turns out that splitting the characters into another column is slightly trickier than I had thought: separate(df$data, into = c("X", "Y"), sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\s*(?=[0-9])")

Comment: You have answered my question 100%, thank you. I think in retrospect, could you please convert to non-scientific notation as I'm struggling not to split the E out of the rest of the string please?